# How do I add a scrollable/zoomable image into the MainView.xib of a Utility Based iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have created a Utility based application  for the iphone in xcode. Basically i have a mainview and a flipside view.

On the main view i have an image as well as a button and a label to go to the flipside view.

However, how do i make the image zoomable/pinchable? All the tutorials and code i have seen has been based on a View Based Application and when i come to copy it in it just comes up with tonnes of errors.

For example, i don't have a Classes folder. Can somebody please provide some sample code for this when you choose Utility Based Application from the new project window when you open xcode.

Answer (score 31):

OK, seeing as you want some code, I see it fitting to do a full tutorial (I'm bored, let's do this!).

Open up Xcode and start a new Utilities based project **(DO NOT TRASH THE OLD ONE)** and name it 'PinchZoomingImages' (without the quotes).  Make sure ARC is turned *OFF*, I like to code the old fashioned way ;).
[image: Xcode template selector]

We will be using a [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) with a [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in it.  Go into the appropriately named 'MainViewController.h" and paste in this code:

```
    #import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    //Both of these iVars are unnecessary with or without ARC, 
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UIImageView * demoImageView;
}
//You can use 'strong' instead of retain, they both mean the same thing
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView * demoImageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender;

@end
```

We need the `UIImageView` and `UIScrollView` pointers because we will be defining them in the .m file.  Speak of the devil, in the .m, paste this in over the whole thing:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController
//It is not necessary to @synthesize any properties if your Xcode version is >=4.5
@synthesize scrollView, demoImageView;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES; // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    demoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PDF-icon.png"]];
    [scrollView addSubview:demoImageView];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(demoImageView.frame.size.width, demoImageView.frame.size.height)];
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
    - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    CGFloat offsetX = (scrollView.bounds.size.width > scrollView.contentSize.width)? 
                      (scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5 : 0.0;
    CGFloat offsetY = (scrollView.bounds.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height)? 
                      (scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5 : 0.0;
    mySubView.center = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX, 
                                   scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for everything but the portrait-upside-down orientation
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender
{    
    //Code created by the Utilities Template
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return demoImageView;
}
@end
```

***SCREECH!*** Did you notice this line here?:

```
demoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PDF-icon.png"]];
```

That **will** crash your project.  you need to drag in an image and copy it's name verbatim (it's cAsE SeNsTiVe) in the `[UIImage imageNamed:@"//your image name + extension"]` message.

Also, notice this line in the `-(void)viewDidLoad` method:

```
scrollView.delegate = self;
```

This is why we put `UIScrollViewDelegate` in a pair of these: "<>" in the .h file, because we need to announce to the compiler that we want to "conform" to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol.

And finally, hook up those IBOutlets (Please, Please hook up the view one first if it isn't already there.  It's a basic and easily forgettable thing):
[image]

and here's what the final product looks like (Upon Launch):
[image]

(Upon zooming, which you can do by holding down the 'option' button in the simulator and dragging the mouse):

[image]

Comment: Hi CodaFi

Thanks for your answer - that was absolutely brilliant. I now have an image that scrolls and zooms. 

Just one question and its probably because i have hooked it up wrong, i copied over the code as you said and the image works perfectly but now when i press the "info" button to go to the Flipside View it just quits the app. Any ideas please?

And also is there a way that the scrollable image could be centered when it opens up rather than just going to the top left of the image? - But if thats too much then dont worry about it im happy enough.

Thanks

Comment: Centering the image has been added to the example and go to the log and tell me what it says.

Comment: Hi there. There are no errors in the build but when i click on the button the log comes up and says:

[Session started at 2011-11-26 18:42:02 +0000.]
2011-11-26 18:42:18.796 JamesApp[257:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/rich/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/3CD5FDBB-6560-4910-B292-A1C26699DEC0/JamesApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'FlipsideViewController''

I am using xcode 3.2.6 and i use 4.2 in the sim as i have a iphone 3g.
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: That means that your NIB name literally doesn't exist.  Check that the name is correct in your message.

Comment: Excellent, got it working now. Thank you so much for your help. Basically, i wanted to get a simple first app under my belt, although its been a lot harder than i thought. Does it come to you in the end? My only previously programming knowledge is VBA and i have felt like giving up at times.

Comment: It doesn't come to you all at once (at least with me).  I view learning Objective-C as like learning French.  It will eventually click, but in the beginning it's jibberish and some things have to be simplified in order for them to work.

Comment: Hi all. i got all of the above working ok. However, i then had the idea of adding a UIWebView to my FlipsideView. I added in the following code on FlipSideViewController.m        
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FullList" ofType:@"HTM" inDirectory:@""];
 NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [webview loadRequest:request];    and also synthesized my UIWebView (called webview) above and also in the .h added in an IBOutlet and @property. However, now the original image doesnt pinch/zoom anymore?

Comment: @CodaFi. Forgot to mention that my UIWebview now works perfectly, just not the original image that CodaFi helped me with. Basically with the extra code in, the UIWebview works and the image doesnt, without the code in, the image works but there is no UIWebview.

Comment: Hello, what would mySubview be?

Comment: Never mind. That has to be demoImageView. Thanks for the nice example.