# How to zoom an image without zooming sub views in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have scroll view with an UIImageView init.I add a button on UIImageView.When i zoom the image then my button is also perform zooming.How can i only zoom the Image not the button.Thanks in advance for you time.

[image]

Comment: Please check 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275234/how-do-i-add-a-scrollable-zoomable-image-into-the-mainview-xib-of-a-utility-base][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275234/how-do-i-add-a-scrollable-zoomable-image-into-the-mainview-xib-of-a-utility-base

Comment: Hello Bharathi D,Thanks for quick reply but this is not solve my problem because when i zoom the Image then the button that actually subview in UIIMageView is also zoom.I want a way that my button will not zoom as well as its position on image will remain same.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any block of related code for this issue?

Comment: Please remove the comments with the code and move it to the OP using `Edit` button below the question.

Comment: Actually there is not a different code for that i simply take a scroll view.Then i enable scrolling property on it.After that i subview an UIImageView in it.In this image view i enable user interaction.After that i subview a UIButton in UIImageView.Now when i zoom the ScrollView(means i zoom the Image) then my UIBUtton(this is in UIImageView) is also zoom and i want that i zoom the UIImageView but the UIButton will not zoom.Thank You.

Comment: I also do not want that when i zoom the image then button on image change the location.As if my button's frame is (100,80,100,60). So it will show on (100,80) coordinates of imageview.So When i zoom the image then the coordinate of button should also change so that the position of button in image will remain same.Thanks.

Comment: I have a hint that can be use for solution...We can use miniumScale for solution.We can change frame size of UIButton during zooming in - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView; UIScrollViewDelegate Method.But i do not know how to use it properly.

Answer (score 3):

Place the button and any other views you do not want to be affected by the `UIScrollView` zooming in a view at the same level as the `UIScrollView`.  Here's an example view hierarchy that was set up for just this purpose.

[image]

The scroll view and anything inside it will zoom (in this case the Image View).
In the UIView below the scroll view (in this case, an image view with the Default.png image) will not zoom when the scroll view is zoomed.

**EDIT:**

To have the button remain in the same place relative to the image add it as a subview to your scroll view, add `UIScrollViewDelegate` to your view controller header.  In your view controller implementation: capture the initial `UIButton` frame in `viewWillAppear`, and use the scroll view delegate `scrollViewDidZoom` method to update the button frame so that is stays in place.  This will also allow the button to move with the image when panning.

Here's the updated view structure:

[image]

The applicable view controller code segments:

```
@interface MyViewController () {
    CGRect initialButtonFrame;

    ...
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    initialButtonFrame = self.button.frame;

    ...
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)sv
{

        self.button.frame = CGRectMake((initialButtonFrame.origin.x * self.scrollView.zoomScale),
                               (initialButtonFrame.origin.y * self.scrollView.zoomScale),
                               initialButtonFrame.size.width,
                               initialButtonFrame.size.height);

...
}
```

Here are a couple of images showing the button staying in place relative to its placement in the image.  Note the button origin is near the top left of the red area near the center bottom of the fireman's coat when not zoomed (first image) and when zoomed (second image).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your interest but if i add the button on any other view then it will not zoom but the image will zoom and the position of button with respect to image is also change.I want that the image will zoom,the button will not zoom(the size of button remain same) and the position of button with respect to image remain same.Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but i already tried it.I need to change the position of button with respect to image.if i do as yours then button will show on screen and the image will zoom behind it so position of button  on image will not change as image zoom.

Comment: Thanks bobnoble...but the position of it do not change appropriately.As if there is a red mark on image and i add a button on image as the corner of button will touch the red mark.Then when i zoom the image ,the button change its position and red mark and button will move away.So this will not solve the issue.I need to keep both(red mark and button) toghether while zooming.

Comment: Let me clarify this, the button position is changed at `scrollViewDidZoom` to keep it near the red mark or any other region, the new position calculation is up to you. What is missing in the answer above i believe is the coordinates (not dimensions) scaling, you'll need to multiply coordinates by the scroll view `zoomScale` value. You can also setup the scrollview subviews position at this method, please try it yourself if interested.

Comment: @A-Live--Thanks A-Live for suggestion but as bobnobel suggest if i impliment this then we handle the zooming problem but the location of button with Image will change....So i tried your way already but the way in which button changes the position is not correct.So this will not work.

Comment: @Jack_iPhone - as A-Live suggested, it is a matter of using the scrollView `zoomScale`.  I modified the button frame calculation in `scrollViewDidZoom` and added a couple of images to show the button position relative to the image view when not zoomed, and when zoomed.

Answer (score 0):

Add the button on the `imageScrollView` superview after the `imageScrollView` so that the button is not scroll view's subview.

Comment: Can you please clearify it more..I do not properly understand it.